# Handling unauthorized users in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, restful-authentication

I'm trying to create REST API using Laravel. I'm using JWT (Tymon\JWTAuth) to authenticate users.

Here is part of my api.php file with /api routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get("match/{id}", "ApiMatchController@getMatch");
Route::middleware('auth:api')->put("match/{id}", "ApiMatchController@editMatch");
```

Now, I'm sending GET request to `/api/match/7`. Authorized user gets match details as expected. Unauthorized user is redirected to root url `/` but I want user to stay on the url, I just want to return HTTP code 401 - Unauthorized. Where can I change this? I can do that inside of `ApiMatchController@getMatch` method but I would like middleware `auth:api` to do that for me. Is there any way how to do this?

Then, I'm sending PUT request to `/api/match/7` with some data. Request from authorized user works just fine but unauthorized user now gets HTTP code 405 - Method Not Allowed (with debug info: `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`). Why? I cleared the route cache and as you can see, there IS a defined route in api.php. This behaviour really happens just with unauthorized user.

Comment: Does it show up on `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Yes, it really does.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921430/laravel-middleware-auth-for-api

Answer (score 0):

About the first part:

> Authorized user gets match details as expected. Unauthorized user is redirected to root url / but I want user to stay on the url, I just want to return HTTP code 401 - Unauthorized. Where can I change this?

This is because your default guard is `web`, so in that case when a user tries to access a protected route it will be redirected to the home page (by default, this can also customized of course).

To change the default guard to `api` go to `config/auth.php` and change it like this:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Note: When making HTTP Requests, add this headers:

```
/** The following tells Laravel that you want a response in json format. */
Accept: application/json
/** The following is for POST/PUT/PATCH requests, it tells the request payload format. */
Content-type: application/json
```

---

About the second part:

> Request from authorized user works just fine but unauthorized user now gets HTTP code 405 - Method Not Allowed

PHP [doesn't handle well](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing) the `PUT`/`PATCH`/`DELETE` methods, in order to bypass this inconvinience do a POST request and then add a hidden `_method` field to the form. 
The value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request method:

Request body (the method is case sentitive):

```
Endpoint:
    /api/match/7

Headers:
    Accept: application/json
    Content-type: application/json

Payload or Body:
    _method: PUT
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the combination of authorize method under controller, and Throwable mentioned in laravel docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors

```
    try{
        $this->authorize('create',Client::class);
    } catch(Throwable $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
```

you can use same approach for your api responses.